# web service - 400 bad request

Tags: c#, php, web-services

i want to consume a php Webservice from C# which is protected by htaccess.
i added the Service by adding a web reference in my VS 2010.

```
mywsfromwsdl myws = new mywsfromwsdl();

System.Net.CredentialCache myCredentials = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
myCredentials.Add(new Uri(myws.Url), "Basic", netCred);
myws.Credentials = myCredentials;
myws.PreAuthenticate = true;

tbxIN.Text = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> "+
            " <test> "+
            " <parm1>4</parm1>  "+
            " <parm1>2</parm1>  "+
            "  </test>";

tbxOUT.Text= myws.func1(tbxIN.Text.ToString());
```

The VS shows an error called 400 Bad REquest my last row.
If i delete the .htaccess File on the server, the pgm works fine, but i cant delete. because other PHP User use the Service.

Can anybody tell me how to send the Credentials correctly ?

By jo

Comment: As an alternative, you can  a)edit the .htaccess file to skip the specific php "webservice" file, so the htaccess will works with all files but your webservice b) move the webservices to a subfolder, then add a .htaccess inside this subfolder that reset the restrictions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to MSDN you shouldn't need the credential cache:

```
 // Set the client-side credentials using the Credentials property.
 ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential("Joe",SecurelyStoredPassword,"mydomain");
 math.Credentials = credentials;
```

Have you tried this method instead of the cache object?  More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.credentials.aspx).

Comment: No, if i try this i get the exception : HTTP-Status 400: Bad Request

Comment: err 400 is not an error of credentials (405)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes C# and Apache clash a bit: in this case, it might be that your client is expecting a `100 Continue` response due to authentication being active, but the server doesn't send it.

This kind of behavior is toggled by this line:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Add it before executing the request.

It's also worth pointing out that when `400 bad request` happens, you might find some useful details in server's logs.

Comment: If i try this i get another error :HTTP-Status 401: Authorization Required.